# Laravel 6.x Password reset with different name email column

Tags: laravel

i can not use laravel password resets , laravel search the column name 'email' but in my database it named 'utilisateur_Email' that why i got this error from laravel ' Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' , how i can customizer my comumn email name in laravel for password reset ? Laravel 6.x Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inside `LoginController` Create a function to define username

```
public function username(){
    return 'utilisateur_Email';
}
```

Comment: thanks , i have that in my loginController https://i.imgur.com/mfHlICX.png , but it not working when reset password